# SQL Query - Filter Largest Date from a group of clients

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have two tables; Customers and Tax Returns

`Customers`:

```
Sysref(PK) FullName
1          ABC Ltd
2          XYZ Ltd
```

`Tax Returns`:

```
CustomerSysref(FK) TaxReturnYear
1                  2016
1                  2015
```

As part of the query I am joining Tax Returns to Customer Table.

```
FROM CUSTOMERS CUS
LEFT JOIN TaxReturns CITR ON CITR.ClientSysRef = CUS.SYSREF
```

I need to query the result of the largest date. Taking the example above I need the query to output the TaxReturnYear for 2016. Can someone please guide me?

If I want to add a where clause which will not display the row when the SubmissionDate is equal to 1900? example;

```
Tax Returns

CustomerSysref(FK) TaxReturnYear SubmissionDate
1                  2016          1900
1                  2015          2016 

WHERE CITR.SubmissionDate != '1900'
```

**The result would be;**

2015 even though 2016 is larger, however the SubmissionDate is 1900.

**End result needs to display;**

Sysref & FullName from table customers

TaxReturnYear and SubmissionDate from table Tax Returns

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result!

Comment: Returning SubmissionDate is a bit different problem. First which one should be returned in this case?    
   `CustomerSysref(FK) TaxReturnYear SubmissionDate`  
   `1                  2016          1900`  
    `1                  2014          2016`  
    `1                  2014          2015`

Comment: `1 2014 2016 and 1 2014 2015` are both good since there should not be more than one TaxReturn in the same year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i got it right

```
...
FROM CUSTOMERS CUS
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT CustomerSysref, max(TaxReturnYear) as TaxReturnYear 
   FROM TaxReturns
   WHERE SubmissionDate != '1900'
   GROUP BY CustomerSysref ) AS CITR
ON CITR.ClientSysRef = CUS.SYSREF
-- added to get submissionDate
LEFT JOIN TaxReturns tr2 
ON CITR.CustomerSysref = tr2.CustomerSysref AND CITR.TaxReturnYear = tr2.TaxReturnYear
```

Corrected according to the question edit.

Comment: Thanks for the code, worked like a charm :) I need to filter out rows when the SubmissionDate is equal to 1900. I have updated the original question above. Would you be able to guide me on this?

Comment: Thanks again for the update. How can I display the SubmissionDate? I have updated the question above with end result. Would you be able to guide me on this?